# Can I enter a second time in France with a valid residence permit but an expired visa?

Tags: study

The first time, I entered France with a long-term student visa for one year, from September 2016 to September 2017. Then immediately I applied for a one-year study permit (student residence permit) from September 2016 to September 2017. Then this year in July 2017 I renewed my residence permit for one year, September 2017 to September 2018, to continue into the second year of my master's.

At the end of December 2017 I will be in India for vacation. I am concerned that in January 2018 when I come back to France whether I can enter France, as I only have a valid study permit here, and my visa expired in September 2017.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to enter France using your residence permit, this is completely normal and very common. Residents with a valid permit do not need a visa.